# what happend status of the journal changed back to the under review from reviews completed?

Tags: publications

I submitted an article to JMES (Journal of Mechanical Engineering and Sciences) on April 3.

On April 10 the status was changed to "Under Review" and on May 7 to "Review Completed", but then on May 22 the status was changed back to "Under Review".

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: My first guess is that the editor didn't like the completed review(s) and decided to get another one.

Comment: A possibility could be that one of the reviewers proposed rejection, other one revision (or acceptance). Then, the editor could have asked for a third review.

Answer (score 1):

After reviews are complete the editor has to make a decision about the paper. There are various possibilities between accept and reject including "seek more information". For some reason the reviews weren't sufficient for the editor to either accept or reject and so they sought more information - putting the paper back into review.

It might have been simple like seeking a clarification from one of the existing reviewers or it might have been asking someone new (or several someones) to take a fresh look.

It might even have been that the editor sent the paper originally to the wrong reviewers and so got back nothing useful.

It is possible that they will respond to a request from you for the reason. Your situation isn't unique.